# How do I determine if an IOException is thrown because of a sharing violation?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5

I have a C# application and I want to copy a file to a new location.  Some times I need to overwrite an existing file. 
when this happens I receive a System.IO.IOException.  I want to recover from a Sharing violation but how do I determine that IOException was returned because the destination file is in use rather then some other reason?  I could look for the "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." message...  But I don't like that idea.

Answer (score 9):

This was the solution I came up with.

```
private void RobustMoveFile( System.IO.DirectoryInfo destinationDirectory, System.IO.FileInfo sourceFile, Boolean retryMove )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string DestinationFile = Path.Combine( destinationDirectory.FullName, sourceFile.Name );
                        if ( File.Exists( DestinationFile ) )
                            sourceFile.Replace( DestinationFile, DestinationFile + "Back", true );
                        else
                        {
                            sourceFile.CopyTo( DestinationFile, true );
                            sourceFile.Delete();
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( System.IO.IOException IOEx )
                    {
                        int HResult = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException( IOEx );        
                        const int SharingViolation = 32;
                        if ( ( HResult & 0xFFFF ) == SharingViolation && retryMove )
                            RobustMoveFile( destinationDirectory, sourceFile, false );
                        throw;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: No need to check for destination file existence, as some other process may create/delete it between the check and the replace/CopyTo operations. Just change your logic that you always create the detination file no matter what, and if this fails, recover or retry.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have stated, you need to get the HResult of the error and check it.  An HResult of 0x80070020 is a sharing violation. The last two bytes of the HResult are the code, [for a sharing violation the code is 0x0020 = 32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d).

In **.NET 4.5**, the `IOException` has a public `HResult` property, so you can just do as follows:

```
try
{
    // do file IO here
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    if ((e.HResult & 0xFFFF) == 32) // 32 = Sharing violation
    {
        // Recovery logic goes here
    }
    else
    {
        throw; // didn't need to catch this
    }
}
```

In **earlier versions of .NET**, however, you need to get the `HResult` by calling [`Marshal.GetHRForException(Exception)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethrforexception(v=vs.80).aspx), so the similar code would be:

```
try
{
    // do file IO here
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    int HResult = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(e)
    if ((HResult & 0xFFFF) == 32) // 32 = Sharing violation
    {
        // Recovery logic goes here
    }
    else
    {
        throw; // Or do whatever else here
    }
}
```

**C# 6.0** allows you to use this syntax to catch only a sharing violation with a `when` clause:

```
try
{
    // do file IO here
}
catch (IOException e) when ((e.HResult & 0xFFFF) == 32) // 32 = Sharing violation
{
    // Recovery logic goes here
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Look for the explicit error codes that you can deal with, for example:

catch (Exception u)
                {
                if (((SocketException)u).ErrorCode == 10035)
...

Take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681391(VS.85).aspx

for error codes, e.g.:

ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION - 32 - 0x20

ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5 - 0x5

ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - 2 - 0x2

Comment: How will the cast from IOException to SocketException will succeed?

Comment: just an example... didn't think it would throw anyone off